# Python: Returning a filename for matching a specific condition

Tags: python-2.7

```
import sys, hashlib
import os

inputFile = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\hashes.txt' 
sourceDir = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test Directory' 

hashMatch = False
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourceDir):
    for filename in files:
    sourceDirHashes = hashlib.md5(filename) 
    for digest in inputFile: 
        if sourceDirHashes.hexdigest() == digest:
            hashMatch = True
            break
if hashMatch:
    print str(filename)
else:
    print 'hash not found'
```

Contents of inputFile =

```
2899ebdb5f7a90a216e97b3187851fc1
54c177418615a90a6424cb945f7a6aec
dd18bf3a8e0a2a3e53e2661c7fb53534
```

Contents of sourceDir files =

```
test
test 1
test 2
```

I almost have the code working, I'm just tripping up somewhere. My current code that I have posted always returns the else statement, that the hash hasn't been found, even although they do as I have verified this. I have provided the content of my sourceDir so that someone case try this, the file names are test, test 1 and test 2, the same content is in the files.

I must add however, I am not looking for the script to print the actual file content, but rather the name of the file.

Could anyone suggest to where I am going wrong and why it is saying the condition is false?

Comment: `for digest in inputFile:` will actually iterate all the characters in the path+filename ( "C", ":", "\", etc.) - it's just a string until you do as @zorg93 suggests (open and read the file)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I've forgot to open the file and read it, silly mistake

Comment: In addition to the hints that were already posted: I think the mistake is mainly caused by misleading identifiers. Using `xxxFileName` instead of `xxxFile` for filenames (or directory names) may help to avoid this kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the inputFile using open(inputFile, 'rt') then you can read the hashes. Also when you do read the hashes make sure you strip them first to get rid of new line characters \n at the end of the lines

Comment: Thank you, I'll make those amendments. Thanks for pointing that out to me